# How to save maps for offline viewing

Tags: android, offline, android-maps

For an app I am currently developing, I would like to save the maps for offline viewing.
Since Google maps now support saving the maps, can anyone please tell me if it is actually
possible to implement the same on our app and is there any specific API for doing that?
Any info would be helpful

thanks in advance

Comment: take snapshot of an map which you have got on app.. then store it onto the sdcard.. then you can view anytime.. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MapView and Android Maps app are two separate beasts. MapViews I don't even think use the same renderer as Google Maps. There is some "offline use", on a per app basis as can be seen by looking at your data/data/ directory. For example, you will find some cached tiles in that dir after viewing some maps. However, that's mainly an optimization for panning and zooming though. It's not really usable as a feature of true offline map support as the cache will eject tiles very quickly.

True offline maps is not supported. The features of Google Maps have not been ported to the MapView or any of the Map sdk within Android apps. That library's api has not even been updated since 2009 :( It's really sad.